# My MSI Installer package failed with Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007045B

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer

I am scheduling my installer in a sequence order just after another installer in a windows batch file.

2:04 am : Installer X scheduled. If exit code = 0 i.e success then my installer gets called.

2:06 am (approx) : The batch file calls my installer after seeing the exit code = 0 of the Installer X.

If my installer runs immediately after Installer X it gets failed with the msi verbose error Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x8007045B.

If my installer runs after 9 minutes delay(2:14 am) of installer X it gets succeeded without any issues.

What could be the reason for this failure? We are calling our installer on the batch file after seeing exit code =0 from the previous installation. Do we need to think still the previous still not release the MSIServer for few mins after it exit with code 0? How do i find who owns the MSIServer service during that time frame where my installer gets failed (2:06 to 2:13am).

Comment: That looks like a pending reboot from the first package. Can you install in reverse order and do a reboot after both packages are installed?

Comment: Stein Asmul what makes you think it's a pending reboot? No one posts more on Windows installer based threads and I respect your knowledge on this subject. I'm just curious from a learning perspective what he posted in his question that leads you to that deduction.

On another note and to add to the conversation, you could always look in the registry for the PendingFileRenames to see if a reboot was pending.

Comment: Hi David, I guess I just did some shooting from the hip. I should perhaps have checked better or provided better links. I just [looked up the error code **`0x8007045B`**](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0x8007045B) and found "ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IN_PROGRESS" - which could be a number of things.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul It worked after i install my package as first package. Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul How do insist my MSI to install though there is a reboot is pending? Kindly advise.